# React and websocket - data manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am trying to implement communication with server through websocket.
Let's say that I can't use Flux or similar libraries. My problem is updating data on server response.

I am not sure how to implement callback functions on server response to update data.

So far I have something like this(not an actual code)

**events.js**

```
const e = require('event-emitter');
var events = e();
module.exports = events;
```

**socket.js**

```
const events = require('./events');

module.exports = {
  var ws;

  init: function(URL) {
    ws = new WebSocket(URL);
    ws.onopen = function() { ... }
    ws.onclose = function() { ... }
    ws.onmessage = function(data) {
      events.emit(data.action, data);
    }

  },

  send: function(data) {
    ws.send(data);
  }
}
```

**model.js**

```
const events = require('./events')
var data = [];

/* listening for some specific event from socket */
events.on("action", doAction);

function doAction(data) {
  events.push(data);

  /* now I have to emit event which react component
  is listening to so it can update data */
  events.emit("viewAction");
  }
}

/* what react component uses to get and render data */
module.exports = {
  get: () => data,
  events: events
}
```

**component.js**

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
const model = require('./model');

var App = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    model.events.on('viewAction', this.refresh);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    model.events.off('viewAction', this.refresh);
  }

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {model.get()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I hope sample makes it clear what I am trying to do and what my problem is. This also makes model event listener not work unless it is included in one of the react components which I am not too happy about.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Okay... where's your component?

Comment: I didn't add component because that's not the part I am struggling with. My problem is data flow and best practise on how I should implement model update on server response. We can just say that after model emits viewAction component works as expected.

Comment: Well, in flux, your model would be called a "store". Components listen to change events from the stores in order to re-render their view. The best practice is to have components directly listen to your event emitted from your model, which is why you should include an example component.

Comment: Also, I guess we might have different philosophies. From my perspective, I don't see anything wrong with including the model in the components that need to listen to it. In fact, that seems to be the only reasonable method to me, and that's exactly how flux works. Data is uni-directional because stores listen to UI events emitted from components, and components listen to change events emitted from stores.

Comment: I updated code with component example. I'd just like to point out one more time that model - component communication is not what's my issue, but handling server - model data flow. Is event emitter like I implemented it valid solution or not. Component is not the one emitting events for store but server.

Comment: It _is_ a valid solution, and it looks relatively elegant to me.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to check if there is something better because I managed to find a lot of examples of how store should communicate with component but not so much of store updating itself on server response.

Comment: No, you seem to misunderstand. In this case the _server_ is the source of truth, not the model. If the model is updating itself, it's only to reflect what is on the server, not to act as the source of truth. All it really should do is relay the data that comes from the server, to the components whose views are dependent on that particular server event. Also, in your example, it would probably be more efficient for the component to have a `shouldComponentUpdate()` method so that it doesn't re-render when it doesn't need to.

Comment: I was unclear then, excuse me. "All it really should do is relay the data that comes from the server" - that's exactly what I am interested in. In this example, I used event emitter to send data to model once server responds and I was looking if there is better approach.

Comment: What you have is the best way to do it. Just make sure that if components receive UI events that affect the state of your application, then you should have the components emit that data to the model so the websocket can relay it back to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your time. That solves my doubts. If you'd post this as an actual answer, I'll mark you as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a simplistic implementation of the [flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html):

[image: flux diagram]

In your case, your action comes from a websocket server response, your dispatcher is the websocket, and your store is the model.

A couple of points to improve your design further:

- Have `this.refresh` in the component save `model.get()` to its state using `this.setState()` so that it internally invokes re-rendering.
- Include `shouldComponentUpdate()` in your component, and compare the old state to the current one in order to determine whether the component really needs to update. *This improves the efficiency of your application dramatically, reducing the amount of reflows in your document*
- Whenever the component receives a UI event, if that event affects the application state in any way, send an event via the websocket back to the server so that the server can send any updates needed to refresh the components views.

  - Optionally, you can instead emit the UI event to the model if the model is able to determine the state of your application from the UI event without communicating with the server, but make sure the model propagates that change to the components listening to it, and to the server so that it doesn't desync from the server which is your application's source of truth.

Good luck on whatever you're writing!